# How to access a HTML element inside a control from the store?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, reactjs-flux

I'm making a login page with ReactJS + Flux pattern, and I've made it, but I'm interested if there is a better way to do it.

My implementation looks something like this:

**LoginForm.jsx**:

```
//imports.....
var LoginForm = React.createClass({
    handleSubmit : function(e){
        //take username, password and rememberMe values from the form....
        var error = this.refs.ErrorMsg.getDOMNode();

        error.innerHTML = ""; //reset the error output for every submit

        //if any field is left empty...
        else{ //make an object and forward it to actions....
            LoginActions.login({
                //set username, password and rememberMe fields...
                ErrorCallback : this.handleError
            }); 
        }
    },

    handleError : function(errorMsg){ 
        //function that displays the error msg inside the error div
        this.refs.ErrorMsg.getDOMNode().innerHTML = errorMsg;
    },

    render : function() {
        return(
            //HTML for the form, and:
            <div ref="ErrorMsg"></div>
        )
    }
});
module.exports = LoginForm;
```

After that, the object I just created goes (unchanged) like a payload to Actions -> Dispatcher -> Store.

**LoginStore.js**:

```
//imports....
var LoginStore = assign({}, ApplicationStore, {
    login : function(payload){
        //this is the method which is called by the Dispatcher

        /*
            take username, password and rememberMe from payload and create a
            new object for AJAX call....
        */

        var successCallback = function(data, statusText, xhr){
            LoginStore.emit(AppConstants.LOGIN); //there is a LOGIN constant...
            /*
                inside data that I get back from ajax call, 
                there is a Error field which contains the 
                "Wrong username or password" message coming from the server 
                after validation if it failed, or if the credentials are
                fine, it contains an empty string....
            */
            payload.errorCallback(null, data.Error);
        }

        AJAXCall(url, loginInfo, successCallback, payload.errorCallback);
    },

    //dispacher registering....
});
module.exports = LoginStore;
```

---

So, due to the fact (correct me if I'm wrong) that I can directly access the error div (or any other react-components HTML element) **only from inside the jsx file where the component is defined**, I made the `handleError` function which travels with the payload up to the store itself, where it can be called in case the error is sent back from the server.

This implementation works, but I'm looking for a more elegant way to do this (if there is any).

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea of react is that you do **not** directly manipulate DOM.
(with some exceptions e.g. adding/ removing listeners).

The react way for you is to put the error message in state, and update state if you get an error message.

And not have the store directly call a function inside the element: components should really be self-containing, responding to props and user input. Instead, put a listener in your component, that fetches new data if your store has changed.

Something like this:

```
var LoginForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { errorMsg : "" };                // start with empty error message
  },

  componentDidMount() {
    // add listener to store here
    LoginStore.addChangeListener(this._onChangeStore);
  }

  handleSubmit : function(e){
    //take username, password and rememberMe values from the form....
    // No need to empty errorMsg here, we do that when we re-render the form

    //if any field is left empty...
    else{ //make an object and forward it to actions....
      LoginActions.login({
        //set username, password and rememberMe fields...
        //no callback here
      }); 
    }
  },

  _onChangeStore : function(){ 
    // ... go get the error message (if any) from your store
    this.setState({ errorMsg : errorMsgFromStore });
  },

  render : function() {
    return(
      //HTML for the form, and:
        <div ref="ErrorMsg">{this.state.errorMsg}</div>
      )
  }
});
```

Put the callback handler on ajax inside the store. Save the error message there and emit a change. Something like:

```
var errorCallback = function(data, statusText, xhr){
  this.errorMsg = data.error;  // save the errorMsg in your store
  LoginStore.emit(AppConstants.ERROR); 
}

AJAXCall(url, loginInfo, successCallback, errorCallBack);
```